setItem coordinates and getitem lat
I use setitem(coordinates) in a previous page that concerns latitude an longitude. I want the next page to use getItem() but just the latitude but I didn't get it.
First page
function storeCoordinates(location) {     
  const coordinates = {   
    lat: location.lat(), 
    lng: location.lng()       
  };            
  localStorage.setItem('coordinates', JSON.stringify(coordinates));    
}

Next page
window.onload = function () {
  var lat = localStorage.getItem('coordinates.lat');
  var IR = (-75 * lat) + 5025;
  var energie_pro = IR * 0.926 * 0.8 * 0.213 * 1.92 * 8;
  document.getElementById('eco_3000').innerText = energie_pro;
}


You can't access the property of the object in localStorage. You need to get the string out of storage, deserialise it to an object, then access its properties:
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  const coordinates = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('coordinates'));
  const lat = coordinates?.lat;

  if (!lat)
    return; 
  
  // rest of your code...
}

Also note the use of addEventListener() over onload and const instead of var in the above example.

Do you have a preference for 'load' over 'DOMContentLoaded' - if not, a preference for document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded') over  window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded')

@mplungjan funnily enough I had the same thought before I posted the answer :) My preference is for load over DOMContentLoaded, as it's more brief and consistent with other event names. I checked compatibility and MDN reckons it's well supported, so good enough for me. I'm aware they're not exactly alike in behaviour, but for 99% of cases they will be interchangeable

True. fixed. Thanks.

The error in the code can be found on this line:
var lat = localStorage.getItem('coordinates.lat');
You can only access local storage items with the key you set it with, in this case 'coordinates'. An improved version of the code will be:
var coordinates = localStorage.getItem('coordinates');
const lat = JSON.parse(coordinates)?.lat;


for the optional chaining
